# Binary Tree with std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm actually using `std::unique_ptr` in order to create a binary tree.

In fact, I use an algorithm tour, which from a distance matrix, calculates the shortest path ! 
In my algorithm, I found myself confronted with the problem of `std::move()` with `std::unique_ptr`.

My tree is built, but only on the root node and don't "make branch".

Here the code where I have the problem :

```
node = std::move(node.get()->addChild());
```

The function `addChild` returns a reference of the `new child (= std::unique_ptr<Node>)`.

I really need to "change" node in order to complete my algorithm. So, How can I fix it ?

Comment: what's the problem exactly? you want to set `node` to the `child`? then your `node = std::unique_ptr<type>(std::move(node.get()->addChild()))`.

Comment: Can't you fix `addChild` and make it return a `unique_ptr`? Then you don't even need the call to `std::move`, just `node = node.get()->addChild();`

Comment: Yes because my algorithm turns until the child had a 2x2 matrix ! So the algorithm works on these nodes but beside, a tree is create and every node had some informations to keep ! At the end of my algorithm, I should be able to run through my tree ! 

tried your solution but it doesn't work. Thanks anyway!

Comment: The return of addChild is `unique_ptr<Node>` but `node = node.get()->addChild();` doesn't work.

Comment: Here the error with your solution :
`little.cpp:66:18: error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>& std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::operator=(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = Node; _Dp = std::default_delete<Node>]’
             node = node.get()->addChild();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `addChild` to return the new node's `unique_ptr` by value instead of returning a reference. The result will be an rvalue without requiring a cast with `std::move`. In your current code, you pass an lvalue reference to `std::move` which results in it still being an lvalue reference and attempting to invoke the copy constructor instead of move constructor of `std::unique_ptr`.